# on image click run javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following image tag:

```
<img src="notification.png" class="notif-btn">
```

and the following div tag:

```
<div class="container-submit" id="not-add">
            
    <!--<i class="notif-btn fas fa-bell fa-10x"><a href="comingsoon.html"></a></i>-->
    <label for="" class="close-btn fas fa-times"></label>
    <div class="header">
        <h3><span class="blue">Get</span> <span class="green">Notified</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <form>
            <span>
                <i class="fas fa-phone-square-alt"></i>
                <input type="tel" placeholder="Mobile No" name="">
            </span><br>
            <span>
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">
            </span><br>
            <span>
                <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
            </span><br>
            <button class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to run a specific java script when clicked on the image it hides the divs and displays it back when clicked again

Comment: How do you imagine that could be done? Have you tried something?

Comment: What problem are you having? Use `addEventListener()` to assign a function to run when you click on the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="image.png" onclick="onClickOnImage()" alt=""/>

<script>
  function onClickOnImage(){
    //add your business logic here
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
<img src="notification.png" class="notif-btn">
```

It can be made to execute Javascript functions by adding an event handler, like this:

```
<img onclick="yourFunction()" src="notification.png" class="notif-btn">
```

This function can be either in the same html file enclosed in a  tag or called from an external file.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="image.png" onclick="onImageClick()"/>

<script>
  function onImageClick(){
    //add logic 
  }
</script>
```